# Why is CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS empty?

Tags: cmake

Consider the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(MyProject)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

add_executable(MyApp main.cpp)

message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

Now, running this:

```
$ cmake --DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <path_to_directory>
```

I get an error that the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is not set. (more accurately - message is called with wrong number of arguments).

I try to understand what exactly the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is causing by default - i.e. how it translates to compiler options/flags.

After building the project, I can clearly see that when running with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE set to Release, the file is smaller (around a third) than when running with it set to Debug, so clearly it has some effect.

Comment: "Why is CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS empty?" - The variable is empty because it contains no flags. "I try to understand what exactly the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is causing by default - i.e. how it translates to compiler options/flags." - So, after your test you know, that by default no compiler flag is set. What is a **problem** you ask us to solve?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, refer to the edit

Comment: If you are looking for Debug-specific flags, they are in [CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) variable.

Comment: I assume not all properties are available via the flags during the configuration phase of cmake; Some could be determined later when generating the build system. It would be preferrable to look up the exact compiler/linker flags used in the generated project, but where exactly you need to look depends on the generator you're using...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must *always* call `cmake_minimum_required` before **any** other commands.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(MyProject)

add_executable(MyApp main.cpp)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Now, to answer your question...

> Why is `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` empty?

Because it is intended to be set on the command line by a user of your build. This is the place where you would inject flags that apply to *all* C++ compiler invocations, regardless of configuration.

> I try to understand what exactly the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is causing by default - i.e. how it translates to compiler options/flags.

On a *multi configuration* generator, like Visual Studio or Xcode, it does nothing. On a *single configuration* generator (like Makefiles or Ninja), the variable sets the active config. That means that all the variables listed [in the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) with `<CONFIG>` in the name get `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` substituted in for `<CONFIG>` and used alongside their non-`<CONFIG>` variants.

There are four configurations that CMake provides:

- `Debug` -- don't optimize and ensure debug symbols are enabled. On GCC this is `-g`.
- `Release` -- full optimization, disable `assert()`. On GCC this is `-O3 -DNDEBUG`.
- `MinSizeRel` -- release mode, but optimize for size. On GCC this is `-Os -DNDEBUG`.
- `RelWithDebInfo` -- release mode, but optimize less to facilitate debugging. Include debug symbols. On GCC this is `-O2 -g -DNDEBUG`.

Comment: my question is: how does the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` e.g. boils down to compiler flags? where can I see **all** the side effects of each configuration? Is it documented etc.?